# Spring Boot Interceptor called anyway of exclude pattterns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

Having a Interceptor registered with:

```
@Override
protected void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new ThymeleafLayoutInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/json/**").excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
}
```

In my understanding the interceptor shall be called for every request but not for requests with
*/static/*
or
*/json/* in their path.
But, the interceptor seems to be called from every resource, also from resources with static in their path.

A print out of in the PostHandle method of my interceptor

```
final ResourceHttpRequestHandler h = (ResourceHttpRequestHandler) handler;
System.out.println(h.getLocations());
```

results in

```
[class path resource [static/]]
```

I tried pattern like
 1. /static/**
 2. /static/*,
 3. /static/
4.  static/

How can this be possible and how can i correct the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling excludePathPatterns twice.

This should do the job

```
@Override
protected void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new ThymeleafLayoutInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/json/**", "/static/**");
}
```